# Valve that opens at low pressure closes high pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

My fluid handling system requires a valve that will open at low pressures (2-6 PSI) and close at high pressures (8 PSI). Is there any commercially available valve that is suitable for this application?

Answer (score 1):

Search back-pressure regulators. Basic idea is they have a dome with a membrane diaphragm pressurized to the control pressure. If the incoming pressure is higher than the dome it pushes the membrane up and shuts the flow.

This is a link to one. [back pressure regulator](https://www.equilibar.com/back-pressure-regulators/?gclid=CjwKCAjw8ZHsBRA6EiwA7hw_segT_ueYpTuKz-_ruca3aIWbnWMW4LKpG7-5ygorPrnxwlxGeznn4hoCnpsQAvD_BwE)